# MongoDB PHP and $out to collection

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there a way to output aggregation result to a collection when using Mongo PHP driver? 
Usually it's done with `$out : "collection_name"` when running aggregate in mongo shell like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match},
    {$group},
    {
        $out : "newcollection"
    }
]);
```

When using PHP driver, like this:

```
    $m = new MongoClient("localhost");
    $c = $m->selectDB($this->mongodb)->selectCollection($this->scrapedCollection);

    $r = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
```

it returns result to `$r` and then you have to iterate over results and insert them one by one in new collection.

I'd like to pass `$out` option to Mongo PHP Driver in aggregate function.

I couldn't find answer in their docs, anyone faced this situation?

Comment: My mistake, it can be done as easy as it is in mongo shell. I missplaced it in pipeline order in php driver and it was throwing exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) is also an aggregation pipeline operator (like $match and $sort are), so use it in the last stage of your pipeline, specifying the output collection name.

Comment: Exactly. My fault was that I was rewriting commands from shell to php driver and that's a whole lot of arrays, so somewhere along the line it really got messed up. Marking it as answer.